# node.js sqlite3 run something after all db.each async callbacks finish

Tags: node.js, sqlite, asynchronous, promise

Can I run something after every row has been processed by db.each?

```
var email = openEmailConnection();
db.each("SELECT * FROM mytable", async (err, row) => {
  var x = await makeNetworkApiCall();
  await email.sendMail({message: "your message: " + x});
  console.log("finished");
});
//somehow call closeEmailConnection() after all async callbacks have finished
```

I don't want to do db.all because that loads everything onto memory. Maybe I could do something with promises and Promise.all?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as an alternative, I suggest to use [`better-sqlite3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) instead. Here, you have an [`iterate()`](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#iteratebindparameters---iterator) function that allows you to process all entries in a for loop like this (from their docu, slightly adapted):

```
const email = openEmailConnection();

const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable');
for (const entry of stmt.iterate()) {
  const x = await makeNetworkApiCall();
  await email.sendMail({message: "your message: " + x});
}

closeEmailConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an anonymous callback function. I used a similar construction to add rows to an array and returning that array after all callbacks of the rows are completed:

```
select = (db, tableName) => {
  const rows = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM ${tableName}`
    db.each(sql, (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      rows.push(row);
    }, () => {
      resolve(rows);
    });
  })
}
```

For your code this would be something like this:

```
const email = openEmailConnection();
db.each("SELECT * FROM mytable", async (err, row) => {
  var x = await makeNetworkApiCall();
  await email.sendMail({message: "your message: " + x});
  console.log("finished");
}, () => { 
   closeEmailConnection();
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. For reference: https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#eachsql--param---callback--complete